# Attachment filename charset-issue after JavaMail update

Tags: java, email, encoding, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

After updating from JavaMail 1.4.5 to 1.6.2 we've experienced issues with attachment filename character set. The problems are at least partially related to `encodeparameters`, as we want to set this to `false` in the new version to avoid receiver having issues with their attachements. This is all executed in a Windows environment.

Using JavaMail 1.4.5 we had this experience:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="Frammøtebekreftelse.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Frammøtebekreftelse.pdf"
```

Using JavaMail 1.6.2 we had this experience:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name*=windows-1252''Framm%F8tebekreftelse.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename*=windows-1252''Framm%F8tebekreftelse.pdf
```

This I assume is fine, but receivers had issues with the `name*`-format, which led us to using `encodeparameters=false`.

Using JavaMail 1.6.2 and `encodeparameters=false` we had this experience:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="FrammÃ¸tebekreftelse.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FrammÃ¸tebekreftelse.pdf"
```

As you can see, this is pretty much what we wan't except now the "Ø"-character is ruined. The rest of the code is identical. I've looked into various means of setting the character encoding, but none seem to address this particular part of the result.

I've also attempted this last version with JakartaMail 1.6.5, with the same result.

**What code or what JVM-option do I need to set to get this right?**

The code for this is pretty vanilla. Below is a MCVE which should demonstrate the issue:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mcve {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
        props.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email@example.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("email@example.com", false));
        message.setSubject("Frammøtebekreftelse");

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
        body.setContent("Hello world", "text/plain");
        multipart.addBodyPart(body);

        MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachment.attachFile("Frammøtebekreftelse.pdf");
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: _Latin Small Letter O With Stroke_ `ø`   is   `0xF8`  in _latin-1_ encoding but `0xC3`,`0xB8` byte sequence in _utf-8_ (and the latter appears as `Ã¸` if interpreted in _latin-1_)…

Comment: @JosefZ thank you. So the MIME is presented as latin-1, while the input was UTF-8 if I read you correctly. Unfortunately I'm still not sure how to specify character encoding for this particular part of the MIME. It seemed to "just work" in previous versions.

Comment: I'd guess that this [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) comes from different settings of sender and receiver mail clients (maybe a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the old look of the headers in JavaMail 1.6.2 I needed to add the following two system properties:

```
props.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");
props.setProperty("mail.mime.allowutf8", "false");
```

Explanation of `mail.mime.allowutf8` from [the patch notes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/JavaMail-1.6-changes.txt):

```
mail.mime.allowutf8:

  If set to "true", UTF-8 strings are allowed in message headers,
  e.g., in addresses.  This should only be set if the mail server also
  supports UTF-8.
```

Unfortunately I'm not completely confident in this not messing up some other features. From my basic inspection the difference is at least the following functionality in `LineOutputStream`.

1.4.5:

```
public void writeln(String s) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = ASCIIUtility.getBytes(s);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.write(newline);
}
```

1.6.2:

```
public void writeln(String s) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes;
    if (allowutf8)
        bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    else
        bytes = ASCIIUtility.getBytes(s);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.write(newline);
}
```

Comment: To those wondering if you should do this: Probably not. We found out that the reason for the upgrade to begin with what trouble with the "ø" when using iOS default mail app. So in order to provide absolute maximum compatability we ended up using `mail.mime.encodeparameters=false` and filtering attachment names to stay within `us-ascii`.